# storybook mui 5 - listbox not found

Tags: material-ui, storybook, testing-library

I write test in storybook for my Select component. Which is basically styled Select from MUI ver. 5. I have trouble to access role="listbox" since it is outside root.

```
<div id="root"> Storybook render Select here</div>
<div role="presentation">
 Here are my Select options
 <ul role="listbox" ></u> - cannot acces this role after click. Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listbox"
<div>
```

This is my story.

```
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof StyledSelect> = (args) => <StyledSelect {...args} />;

export const ChangeOption = Template.bind({});

ChangeOption.args = {
  labelId: 'dafault-select-label',
  id: 'default-select',
  label: 'select-under-test',
  sx: { width: 240 },
  value: 1,
  children: [
    <StyledMenuListItem key={'none1'} value={-1}>
      None
    </StyledMenuListItem>,
    <StyledMenuListItem key={1} value={1}>
      Option 1
    </StyledMenuListItem>,
    <StyledMenuListItem key={2} value={2}>
      Option 2
    </StyledMenuListItem>,
    <Divider key="div3" />,
    <StyledMenuListItem key={3} value={3}>
      Option 3
    </StyledMenuListItem>,
  ],
};

ChangeOption.play = async ({ canvasElement, globals }) => {
  // Arrange
  const canvas = within(canvasElement);
  const selectElement = canvas.getByLabelText(/select-under-test/i);
  await expect(selectElement).toHaveTextContent(/option 1/i);
  // Act
  await userEvent.click(selectElement);
  const listbox = await canvas.getByRole('listbox');

  // Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listbox"
  
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the canvas cannot find the opened Select menu is because it is rendered using a [Portal](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-portal/) and therefore exists outside of the canvas DOM. One way to get around this is to use the screen object from `@storybook/testing-library`. It's a not a great solution, but here is how you can use it:

```js
import { screen, userEvent, within } from '@storybook/testing-library';

// ...

ChangeOption.play = async ({ canvasElement, globals }) => {
  // Arrange
  const canvas = within(canvasElement);
  const selectElement = canvas.getByLabelText(/select-under-test/i);
  await expect(selectElement).toHaveTextContent(/option 1/i);
  // Act
  await userEvent.click(selectElement);

  // Get the listbox
  const listbox = within(await screen.findByRole('listbox'));

  // Click an option
  const option = listbox.getByText(/Option 3/i);
  userEvent.click(option);

  // Now you can test what you expect to change on the canvas
};
```

This comes with the caveat that you are now searching on the entire Storybook screen, which includes everything on the page and not just in the Storybook canvas. So, if there are other listboxes on screen, you may run into issues.

I would love to see a better solution if you or anyone else has one!

Comment: ugh I have to `await` 24 hours to award the bounty!  Thanks for the reminder about `Portal` and the implications.